# SurfaceControl: @!@! Throw TooManySurfacesException [SurfaceView ] [Android]

Tags: android, exception, surfaceview, android-videoview

I have an activity with recyclerview with few images and videos.
I am getting following error after few seconds of opening the activity.
Trace dont have much information.Please help if anyone has faced the similar issue.
Thanks in advance for the help.

```
      09-17 17:54:59.953  4876 12434 D WindowManager: finishDrawingWindow: Window{8f2361 u0 com.abc.cde/--------} mDrawState=HAS_DRAWN
     09-17 17:54:59.964  4341  4341 E SurfaceFlinger: createLayer() failed, already application created very many surfaces [SurfaceView - -----------------@9d1aef3@0[20719]]
     09-17 17:54:59.965 20719 20719 E SurfaceComposerClient: SurfaceComposerClient::createSurface error Broken pipe
     09-17 17:54:59.965 20719 20719 E SurfaceControl: @!@! Throw TooManySurfacesException [SurfaceView ---------------y@9d1aef3@0[20719]]
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView: A process tried to create too many surfaces
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView: android.view.WindowManager$TooManySurfacesException
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.SurfaceControl.nativeCreate(Native Method)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.SurfaceControl.<init>(SurfaceControl.java:702)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.SurfaceControl.<init>(SurfaceControl.java:72)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.SurfaceControl$Builder.build(SurfaceControl.java:454)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.SurfaceView$SurfaceControlWithBackground.<init>(SurfaceView.java:1452)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.SurfaceView.updateSurface(SurfaceView.java:644)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.SurfaceView$2.onPreDraw(SurfaceView.java:181)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.ViewTreeObserver.dispatchOnPreDraw(ViewTreeObserver.java:991)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2981)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1850)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:8455)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:949)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:761)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:696)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:935)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:873)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:214)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6981)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:493)
     09-17 17:54:59.968 20719 20719 E SurfaceView:  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1445)
     09-17 17:54:59.969 20719 20719 I Process : Sending signal. PID: 20719 SIG: 9
```